# Subfunctor of finitely definable elements

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a category of sets and functions and $F:\mathcal{C}\to Set$ is a presheaf.

We can define a subfunctor of $F$, $F^*$, as follows:

- $F^*(A) := \{a \in F(A)\mid$ for some finite $Y\subseteq A$ for any $B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and $h,h':A\to B$, $F(h)a=F(h')a$ whenever $hy=h'y$ for all $y\in Y\}$.
- $F^*(h):=F(h)$

Intuitively this corresponds to the finitely definable elements of $F$, in the sense that a finite bit of data from $A$ fixes the behavior of the elements of $F^*(A)$. I've added an example in the comment below.

Does this sort of construction have a name (or is it subsumed by a more general notion)? Looking for further connections and references here.

Comment: Do you have any (nontrivial) concrete examples of such functors?

Comment: How about: $F(A)$ be infinite sequences on $A$, $A^\omega$, with $h:A\to B$ acting on sequences in the obvious way ($F(h)(g)(n) = g(h(n))$, when $g\in A^\omega$). Then $F^*(A)$ intuitively ought to be the infinite sequences in $A^\omega$ that made up of finitely many different elements of A (i.e. with finite range when thought of as functions).

Comment: I think you mean $F(h)(g)(n) = h(g(n))$ . Moreover you have to clarify what you mean by "$hy = h'y$ for all $y\in Y$, and also "some finite $Y\subset A$", as $A$ is an object of $\mathcal C$.

Comment: Re the first thing, yes that's what I meant to write. I don't understand the second issue. $\mathcal{C}$ is a category of sets and functions so finiteness, set membership and function application just have their ordinary meanings.